# Choosing entries of a matrix with probability 1/2

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory

Let $n ≥ 1$ be a positive integer. An $n × n$ matrix $M$ is generated as follows: for each $1 ≤ i, j ≤ n$, we randomly and independently write either $i$ or $j$ in the $(i, j)$th entry, each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Let $E_n$ be the expected value of $det (M)$.

For which values of $n;\ E_n\ge0$?

I have no idea how to approach.

Comment: I found that for $E_1=1; E_2=-\frac{1}{4};\ E_n=0 \forall n\ge3$. Is that correct?

Comment: Problem M2 from the [PRIMES 2017 problem set](http://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2017/entpro2017usa.pdf)